# How to create new array with begins and limit numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create with transforming old array.

```
arr1 = [ 4,  26,  40,  53,  58,  68,  73,  86, 91, 114, 119, 132, 137, 147, 152, 165, 170, 183, 188, 201, 206, 208, 215, 220, 233, 238, 250, 255, 267, 272, 284, 289, 301, 306, 318, 323 ]
```

I want to create like

```
newArr = [[4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ..., 24,25], [26,27,28 ..., 39], [40,...,52], ...]
```

As you see in `arr1`, the number is the beginning, and the `next item - 1` is the last number. How I can do like this. The last number is `325` in `arr1`
I tried `chunk_array`, but it does not work.

Comment: can you be more clear, and include that part of the desired output in your question instead of `...]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `map` and `Array.from` and then get all except the last one with `slice(0, -1)`.

```js
const arr = [4, 26, 40, 53, 58, 68, 73, 86, 91, 114, 119, 132, 137, 147, 152, 165, 170, 183, 188, 201, 206, 208, 215, 220, 233, 238, 250, 255, 267, 272, 284, 289, 301, 306, 318, 323]
const result = arr.map((e, i) => Array.from(Array((arr[i + 1] || e) - e), (_, j) => e + j)).slice(0, -1)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to achieve the desired result

```js
const arr1 = [
  4, 26, 40, 53, 58, 68, 73, 86, 91, 114, 119, 132, 137, 147, 152, 165, 170,
  183, 188, 201, 206, 208, 215, 220, 233, 238, 250, 255, 267, 272, 284, 289,
  301, 306, 318, 323,
];

const result = arr1.map((el, i, src) => {
  const start = el, end = src[i + 1];
  return Array.from({ length: end - start }, (_, i) => i + start);
});

result.pop();
console.log(result);
```

**2)** You can also do as

```js
const arr1 = [
  4, 26, 40, 53, 58, 68, 73, 86, 91, 114, 119, 132, 137, 147, 152, 165, 170,
  183, 188, 201, 206, 208, 215, 220, 233, 238, 250, 255, 267, 272, 284, 289,
  301, 306, 318, 323,
];

const result = arr1.map((el, i, src) => {
  const start = el, end = src[i + 1] ?? start;
  return Array(end - start)
    .fill(0)
    .map((_, i) => i + start);
});

result.pop();
console.log(result);
```

**3)** You can also use reduce here:

```js
const arr1 = [
  4, 26, 40, 53, 58, 68, 73, 86, 91, 114, 119, 132, 137, 147, 152, 165, 170,
  183, 188, 201, 206, 208, 215, 220, 233, 238, 250, 255, 267, 272, 284, 289,
  301, 306, 318, 323,
];

const result = arr1.reduce((acc, start, i, src) => {
  const temp = Array((src[i + 1] ?? start) - start)
    .fill(0)
    .map((_, i) => i + start);
  if (temp.length) acc.push(temp);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Essentially the same answer as was already posted.

Comment: Imagine two coders coming up with two very similar answers within minutes of each other.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [ 4,  26,  40,  53,  58,  68,  73,  86, 91, 114, 119, 132, 137, 147, 152, 165, 170, 183, 188, 201, 206, 208, 215, 220, 233, 238, 250, 255, 267, 272, 284, 289, 301, 306, 318, 323 ]

const result = data.map((n, index, array) => Array.from({ length: ( array[index+1] || n+1 ) - n }, (_, i) => i+n));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Comment: Shouldn't be last number `323` included in the result?